# How is it possible to add a space before and after string of every row

Tags: r

Having a dataframe with one column:

```
df <- data.frame(mytext = c("text1", "another one", "etc"))
```

How is it possible to add a space character at the start and end of every string in every row.

Example result

```
df <- data.frame(mytext = c(" text1 ", " another one ", " etc "))
```

Comment: Try `paste(' ', df$mytext, ' ')`

Comment: also: `sub("(.+)", " \\1 ", df$mytext)`

Comment: @sotos more like `paste("", df$mytext, "")` or you'll end up with 2 spaces both at the beginning and at the end

Comment: @Cath You are right. I meant to write `paste0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the paste function:

```
df$mytext <- paste0(' ', df$mytext, ' ')
```